# How do I make an html button to perform a javascript toggle?

Tags: javascript, html, button, toggle, local-storage

Here is my javascript:

```
if(!localStorage.status) localStorage['status'] = 1;
toggle(2);
enable.onclick = function(){toggle(0)};
disable.onclick = function(){toggle(1)};
function toggle(n){
     /// code here not relevant to this question
    }
}
```

Here's my html:

```
<form name="thename">
<input type="checkbox" name="option1"> Toggle it
</form>
```

Now how do I connect the javascript to the html so that checking the box toggles value of 0 and unchecking the box toggles value of 1?

Clarification:

The value that needs to be 0 or 1 is the localstorage value for 'status'. That's the value we are toggling.

Comment: Do you want one button to enable and one to disable, or one to do both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this (javascript):

```
if(!localStorage.status) localStorage.status = 1;
var btn = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];

btn.onclick = function()
{
    if(btn.checked === true)
    {
        toggle(1);
    }else{
    toggle(0);
    }
};
function toggle(n){
    localStorage.status = n;
    alert(localStorage.status);
}
```

I used dot notation for **localStorage['status']** instead, because it is better written in dot notation.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/q27yU/1) is the fiddle (will alert 1 when you check the checkbox, will alert 0 when you uncheck it).

Comment: @user2651403 It's correct now.  I was confused because I thought you wanted '1' and '2'.  Now it will toggle with '0' and '1'.

Comment: I think this answer is incorrect, I already did onclick in the javascript

Comment: @user2651403 Okay, read your question's edit, and using this as your javascript should do what you want (toggle with 1 if checked, 0 if not checked)

Comment: your answer is incorrect because you only connected it halfway which doesn't do anything.

Comment: I see you made a new answer, but unfortunately you removed all the localstorage which is the most important part.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44572/discussion-between-man-of-snow-and-user2651403)

Answer (score 1):

You could either use `<button>` or `<input type="button">` and include `onclick=""`.
For example:

```
<button onclick="toggle(0)">Enable</button>
<button onclick="toggle(1)">Disable</button>
```

OR

```
<input type="button" onclick="toggle(0)" value="Enable">
<input type="button" onclick="toggle(1)" value="Disable">
```

Comment: How do I make it the same button?

Comment: and are you suggesting to remove `toggle(0)` and `toggle(1)` from my javascript?

Comment: and also I already have onclick in my javascript. I'm confused as to how you think adding another onclick to my html will connect it to the javascript?

Comment: I think this answer is incorrect. I already declared onclick in my javascript. I don't think we should be adding it to my html also.

Comment: You would need to store whether the toggle was on or off.  Then, you can use php: `<input type="button" onclick=<?php if ($enabled) {echo 'toggle(1)';} else {echo 'toggle(0)';} ?> value="Toggle">` $enabled should be set to either true or false depending if it is enabled or disabled.

Comment: Yes, you do not need the onclick in the javascript if you use this method.  You only need the function.

Comment: In that case, employ an `if/else` statement in your javascript function checking if the variable `enabled` is true.  If it is, set n to `1`.  Otherwise, set it to `0`.  Therefore you do not need to include 1 nor 0 in the html code.

Comment: you didn't connect this to the javascript or localstorage at all.

Comment: Also, you would obviously need to employ a method of checking if it is enabled and setting the enabled variable accordingly.

Comment: @ Anonymous, I already have that, what I need is the answer to *this* question.

Comment: This would be the html: `<input type="button" onclick="toggle()" value="Toggle">` and this would be the javascript: `function toggle(){}` and inside the function, you define `n` based on if the thing you are trying to toggle is enabled.